Как загружать объект в S3 с помощью presigned_url?
У меня в приложении юзер сначала должен заполнить определенную форму с данными и прикрепить к ним фотку. Я должен на бэке сделать эндпоинт, который будет генерировать presigned url, отдавать ее на фронт и уже на фронте я загружу файл напрямую в хранилище и потом передам ссылку на объект вместе с данными на другой эндпоинт, я правильно понимаю?

Можешь через бэк протащить
